# how to customize texts in wordpress control panel

Tags: wordpress

I want to change main texts in wordpress control panel.

For example I want change the dashboard menu's text to "Main Page".Other menus and words and texts take change like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the translation feature to your custom language.
First, download the translation file here:
https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/?locale=en_GB
its an english (UK) translation.
then edit every string you need to change in .po files(a standard text files) and compile it into .mo file.
you could use poedit  (a free software) to do those two jobs even easier.
http://poedit.net/
Then apply your custom language by creating a directory inside wp-admin named **languages** and put your custom .mo files there.

Refference:https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language